# How to show button on file select in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

**I want to hide a button by default and show it after the selection of file from the file input filed but i don't know how i can achieve this please anyone can solve this thanks in advance**

*this is my code to hide and show button on the file selection*

```
     <form onSubmit={changeImage} encType="multpart/form-data">
      <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
        <label>
          <Input
            accept="image/*"
            id="icon-button-file"
            type="file"
            name="image"
            onChange={fileSelectHandler}
          />
          <IconButton
            htmlFor="buttonHide"
            color="primary"
            aria-label="upload picture"
            component="span"
          >
            <PhotoCamera />
          </IconButton>
        </label>
        <label>
          <Button variant="contained" id="buttonHide" hidden type="submit">
            Update
          </Button>
        </label>
      </Stack>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use conditional rendering with a state:

Something like that:

```
    const [Show, setShow] = useState(false);
```

And place those lines of code in the return/render function:

```
{
 Show && (<div><div/>)
}
```

When you want to display the code of block just change the state:

```
setShow(true);
```

Comment: thanks @Dor Schreiber for your answer it's solve my problem

Comment: @AmirShahzad Glad I could help! :)